# Why does the \LinesNumbered command not work of the algorithm2e package in beamer frame?

Tags: beamer, algorithm2e, line-numbering

I want to  add line number from the fourth line, but the `\LinesNumbered` command doesn't work at all.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \KwSty{type} val : \KwSty{real}$[k]$\;
    \KwSty{type} ind : \KwSty{int}$[k]$\;
    \KwSty{type} ptr : \KwSty{int}$[m+1]$\;
    \LinesNumbered
    \ForEach{row $i$}{
      \For{$l=ptr[i]$ \KwTo $prt[i+1]-1$}{
     $ y[i] \leftarrow y[i]+val[l] \cdot x[ind[l]]$ \;
      }
    }
  \end{algorithm}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Its output is:

[image]

But I want it looks like this:(And how can I add the red color for `ind[l]`?)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a problem of the `frame` environment... `\LinesNumbered` works only if issued outside the `algorithm` environment.

But you can use

```
\everypar={\nl}
```

instead.

MWE (I've also added red text coloring for `ind[l]` and improvements for math operators)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\DeclareMathOperator{\ind}{ind}
\DeclareMathOperator{\val}{val}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ptr}{ptr}
\DeclareMathOperator{\row}{row}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \KwSty{type} val : \KwSty{real}$[k]$\;
    \KwSty{type} ind : \KwSty{int}$[k]$\;
    \KwSty{type} ptr : \KwSty{int}$[m+1]$\;
    \everypar={\nl}
    \ForEach{$\row i$}{
      \For{$l=\ptr[i]$ \KwTo $\ptr[i+1]-1$}{
     $ y[i] \leftarrow y[i]+\val[l] \cdot x[\textcolor{red}{\ind[l]}]$ \;
      }
    }
  \end{algorithm}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To be honest, It is my first time to come across the command `\everypar`. Can you explain its meaning?

Comment: @CodingTheLife Of course. `\nl` is the command to manually add a line number in the `algorithm` environment. `\everypar={\nl}` tells LaTeX to issue that command every time a `\par` is issued. The definition of `\LinesNumbered` is in fact, `\newcommand{\LinesNumbered}{\setboolean{algocf@linesnumbered}{true}\renewcommand{\algocf@linesnumbered}{\everypar={\nl}}}`